# How to use the API KEY for google map

Tags: android, google-maps, metadata

I'm trying to add a google map to my Android application. I have an API KEY from google,
and used it in my Android Manifest:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="my API KEY" />
```

But I faced this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Excepted 4030500
>   but found 0. You must have the following declaration within the
>    element:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"     
    android:value:"@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

please help me.

Comment: did you read the error, it clearly says what you need to add to your manifest

Comment: This is a job for ... **Captain Obvious!**

Answer (score 1):

this happened when google updated the google play services. Simply do what it says in the error log. Add that line to your manifest

Comment: It says :
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: <meta-data android name="com.google.android.gms.version" android value:"@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
and I think I just have that but it doesn't work!!

Comment: the tag you have is for your map api key, since google updated their play services, the new lines are required also. Add <application> element: <meta-data android name="com.google.android.gms.version" android value:"@integer/google_play_services_version"/> below your maps meta data

Comment: That should be all there is to it. Try refreshing and cleaning your project + the google play services project. Try uninstalling the app then reinstalling after refreshing and cleaning the build

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your manifest file under application Tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```